# Is there anyway I can allow a class to be added into second tab window on tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time
from tkinter import ttk
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x800+0+0")
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text='Recommendation')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Business')
tabControl.add(tab3, text='Customer')

class TestApp(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
        self.main.title('Hotel Review')
        f = Frame(self.main)
        f.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        df = None
        self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df,
                                showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
        pt.show()
        return
dataframe = TestApp()
tabControl.pack(expand=50, fill="both")
root.mainloop()
```

Hi guys so this is part of my code and I'm trying to add this class called "TestApp" into my second tab window called "Business". Is it possible for it to appear on my second tab or tkinter will restrict it.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. What's the issue here?

Comment: I can only allow it to appear on the first tab but not the second tab.

Comment: I don't see an attempt at putting it on `tab2`, the frame for `Business`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parent the `pandastable.Table` to `tab2`

I removed the `TestApp` fluff, because it's not really necessary here.

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Label

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table

root = Tk()
root.title("Hotel Review")
root.geometry("1000x800+0+0")

# Create tab control and tabs
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

# Populate tabs
Label(tab1, text="Recommendations here").pack()
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
)
tab = Table(
    tab2, dataframe=df, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True
)
tab.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
Label(tab3, text="Customer stuff!").pack()

# Add tabs to tab control
tab_control.add(tab1, text="Recommendation")
tab_control.add(tab2, text="Business")
tab_control.add(tab3, text="Customer")
tab_control.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
root.mainloop()
```